# Area of a polygon?

Tags: geometry, area

[Polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8xfU.jpg)

[image]

What is the area of this polygon. (question 70)

Anyone think they can show me how it's done?

The image is in link form posted above.

Comment: What value did you get for $x$ by using the Pythagorean Theorem?  What value is listed for the "correct" answer?

Comment: ?? why was me putting the image into the text reverted ?

Comment: kindly show us your working.

Comment: Is the 7m supposed to be the length of that side or, as I suspect, the altitude of the triangle (the dashed line)?

Comment: It is the length of the side of the figure. Not for the dashed line it seems.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn't a site that will solve your homework for you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Pythagorean theorem:$$x=\sqrt{24^2+7^2}$$

Also the area of the triangle is $A=\frac{7 \times 24}{2}$

and the area of the square is $B=24^2+7^2$

Therefore $A+B=...$

Comment: I suspect that the 7m is the *altitude*, not the side length.

Comment: @amd: how do you interpret the $24$m?

Comment: As the length of the upper edge. The diagrams are ambiguous to my eye, but there’s no point to showing the altitude if the 7m is a side length. It looks like the previous problem also gives the length of an altitude rather than a side.

Comment: I believe 7m is the side length of the right triangle.

Comment: If I follow @MariosGretsas input then A+B= 128. So thus the area of the polygon would be 128? Then what would be the use of the Pythagorean theorem? That equals out to 25.

Comment: @Don we use the Pythagoreian to find $x$(the hypoteneuse) ...and the whole  area is 709 because $A=625$ and $B=84$